# How to disable sip auto answer

Tags: empathy, voip, sip

I just noticed that my **SIP** (*Session Initiation Protocol*) client automatically answer ALL incoming calls. Not good. I'm using telepathy-sofiasip with Empathy. I wonder how I can disable the auto-answer?

Answer (score 1):

Removing Telepathy seems to have fixed the problem. (Although Telepathy-logger keeps crashing regularly.)

1250  apt-get remove telepathy*

1251  apt-get purge

1252  apt-get autoremove

1254  apt-get update

1255  apt-get install empathy

1256  apt-get install telepathy-sofiasip